# Bootstrap Modal with Danger State Class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap offer [Contextual Alternatives for Panels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-alternatives) that make it easy to style the panel by adding any of the contextual state classes such as panel-warning or panel-danger.

Does bootstrap offer a similar mechanism for [Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)? Or is there an easy way to apply the "panel-warning" class to a modal?

I tried using `<div class="modal modal-warning">` and even `<div class="modal panel-warning">`, but neither worked.

Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can but it might be dangerous.
I've applied `panel-warning` and `panel-heading` to the class `modal-content` and `modal-header`

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content panel-warning">
        <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

@pimlottc has noticed the top `border-radius` is slightly different.
Here is the fix:

```
.panel-heading
{
    border-top-left-radius: inherit; 
    border-top-right-radius: inherit;
}
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/7Xeb6/).

Comment: Thanks! I had left out the panel-heading class. I agree, this is potentially dangerous. Simply styling the modal would be nearly as easy in this case.

Comment: Based on Bootstrap 3.0.0, 'panel-warning' class should be added on 'modal-content', not 'modal-dialog'. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xeb6/2/

Comment: @idearibosome: Thanks for the info. Something must have changed since my answer. Updated my answer with your info. Cheers.

Comment: Note that panels have a smaller border-radius than modals.  It's slight but noticeable.

Comment: If you change the selector for the border radius fix to .modal-header.panel-heading you won't have to worry about it interfering with panel styling in other contexts.

Comment: Try to add `bg-warning` class to `modal-header`. That is completely enough.

Answer (score 12):

### .alert-[context]

As `.alert`s are a fairly simplistic component, it may mean a lesser likelihood of side-effects.

My approach in the past has been adding the `alert-danger` (or whatever context) class to `modal-header` & sometimes `modal-footer`. You can go a step further and add it to `modal-body`. To me it seems more elegant to only put it on the header -- but I won't tell you how to style your markup ;)

Comment: I liked this idea, but quickly found it frustrating that alerts lack a primary and default context, which prevents you from matching the modal triggered by a button to its modal in some cases.

Comment: Hmm. Good point T.J. Modals always retain JS behavior so why not have this an option -- maybe even the default.

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap 4 replaces panels with [cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/). Warning and danger backgrounds can be applied to a card with the following Bootstrap classes:

```
 bg-warning
 bg-danger
```

You can simply add one of these background classes to the container that has the 'modal-content' class for your [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/):

```
class="modal-content text-white bg-warning"
```

[image]

`bg-danger` gives a red background

You can use a card *within* the modal to highlight a warning message inside the modal like this:

[image]

**Markup:**

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">My title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        You can't undo this
        <div class="card text-white bg-warning mt-3 p-2">
            This is a warning - bad things may happen
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onConfirm()"><ng-container i18n>Yes</ng-container></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onCancel()"><ng-container i18n>No</ng-container></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```